# Jquery masonry layout over several containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

Is it possible to have a Jquery Masonry layout over several div containers? Fill the first div, and when it's full, fill the second one, and so on...
(The content is loaded dynamically from a feed)

Having a way to tell when a container is full would be a good start, but Masonry doesn't provide such a method.

Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: This is more like CSS Regions. Check this out http://html.adobe.com/webstandards/cssregions/

Comment: Thanks for this, looks great, but that's not really what I'm looking for. My boxes can be images or paragraphs of various length, with different css styles, and random width and height. So I really need to have a Masonry layout.

Comment: You could programmatically append new Masonry containers to your DOM and append new Masonry bricks to them. Read about how to generate DOM elements at runtime and then show what you've tried so we can help.

Comment: My problem is not to append Masonry containers to the DOM, but rather to test if a masonry container is full. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: **The link above is now broken**, and it looks like [**CSS Regions never caught on**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions).